# Using Cubemap/Mirrorball Texture on a material

Tags: shaders, reflection, shader-nodes

I'm looking for a way to create a cubemap effect that mimics that seen in Source Engine materials, either through use of the cubemap faces or the mirrorball/sphere that is included in some of the textures, seen in this image patched together from one of Valve's cubemaps

[image]

I would prefer to be able to replicate the cubemap effect that works like a cube with inverted normals but on a per-material basis and regardless of UVs, but at minimum I'd like to replicate the effect of using the sphere as a matcap, which I'd assume would be WAY easier

[image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I know there are built-in reflection functionality, but the goal of this is to be able to use pre-existing textures that likely aren't formatted for blender's current forms of environment mapping

Answer (score 3):

### Cubemap

- Add a *Cube*, *Shade > Smooth*
- Assign two modifiers - **Subsurf** > *Simple* = 4 (to get more geometry) and **Cast** modifier > *Sphere > Factor* = 1
- under *Object Properties > Visibility* > **disable Shadow**
- create a material just with **Glossy** shader > *Roughness* = 0, add *Image textur*e node (disconnected but selected - *Active*) with a *New* one

[image]

- under Render Properties > Bake

[image]

### **Mirror ball**

it can be rendered directly with blender's camera ... in *Camera Properties* set type **Panoramic > Mirror Ball** ... if you need to have it as a part of Cubemap texture you would have to merge them in *Compositor*.

[image]

[image]

Cubemap /Mirrorball example file ...

[image]

---

To generate **CubeMap without UV** ... assign each side of *Cube* individual material with individual *Image Texture* (again this node has to be *Active* in each material to be succesfully baked).

Comment: Do you know how to control render settings using the bake method?  For example, the exposure seems different from a standard render, and the `Scrambling Distance` option seems to be ignored in Blender 3.1.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug ... Bake is controlled by the same parameters as regular render. Previously some features wasn't available (like denonising), that is possible now thanks to rewritten Cycles to version X, that is merge in 3.x now. I'm on Mac so I can't confirm Scrambling Distance feature for Optix, but it is possible it is not available for baking ... and that is why you see also differences in exposure. Denoising, especially in combination with low Samples, makes a huge difference in a result.