# How can I render a CubeMap with EEVEE

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render 6 images of my world in EEVEE to form a perfect cubemap, but when I render the images they don't fit together perfectly. I would like to know if there is any specific configuration for this or any other way to achieve this result without using Cycles.

Here an exemple:
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the way they fit? Are there margins that look strange, or are the components in the wrong place altogether?

Comment: The images don't complete with each other, I don't know how to configure blender to fit the images

Comment: I would assume it's just a matter of arranging your UV "squares" properly, and ensuring there is no margin.  If you want, you can upload an example of your project here - https://blend-exchange.com/ - and we can take a closer look at it.

Comment: Here is a way ... just Eevee has no Bake feature so Cycles was used https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249404/2214